# I can not see dropdownlist from my navbar in dashboard screen with leaflet

Tags: html, css, reactjs, navbar

I have a problem about my nav bar in react. I made navbar as a different compononet. As you can see in this [seabledropdownnavbarlist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxFgQ.png) picture, I can see all menu over the form screen. But I made a dashboard screen and I used leaflet map. As you can see in this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOcy3.png) picture the dropdownlist is over the div tag but under the map, so i can not see some of my menuitems. Is that related with leaflet map or related with my design. If you help me i will be very happy. it is not curical but it is disturbing me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's a z-index problem. In your CSS change z-index of your dropdownlist.

For exemple in your CSS

```
.dropdownlist {
 z-index: 1;
}
```

[MDN z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

Comment: sorry unfortunateyly, it does not work. it does not effect "<Map  ref={refMap} center={position} zoom={zoom} style={{ height: '400px', width: '100%' }}>" area.

Comment: And if you change th z-index of all the navbar with a big index ?

Comment: yes i did. I t hink it is related with the map. the rest of the components act as they should be. Only for map we are having trouble.

Comment: You were right. I revise my design and gave a zIndex and it worked. Thanks.